# Draw a Radiant Gradient: <Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I'm very very new on CoreGraphics and I don't know how to draw a radiant gradient on a `CALayer`.

I have found that I have to use [CGContextDrawRadialGradient](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) to draw a radiant gradient.

Searching on Google, I see that I have to add the radiant gradient to CALayer's content, but to draw it I need a [CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGContextRef), and I don't know how to get this `CGContext`.

**Do you know how can I do it?**

I have found this [tutorial](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2012/06/16/the-jungle-part-7-quartz-demos-section-2-of-3/), but it also uses `CGContext`.

My code is this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *testView;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

- (void)drawRadiantGradient;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize testView = _testView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self drawRadiantGradient];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)drawRadiantGradient
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat redBallColors[] = {
        1.0, 0.9, 0.9, 0.7,
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8
    };
    CGFloat glossLocations[] = {0.05, 0.9};
    CGGradientRef ballGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, redBallColors, glossLocations, 2);
    CGRect circleBounds = CGRectMake(20, 250, 100, 100);
    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(50, 270);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(70, 300);
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, ballGradient, startPoint, 0, endPoint, 50, 0);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circleBounds);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

I want to create a `CALayer`, draw a radiant gradient, and add this `CALayer` to `_testView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either draw into your own context (for example an image context that you created using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`

or

become the delegate of that layer and draw into the layers graphics context using `drawLayer:inContext:`

It sounds to me like you want to do the second option. You would create the CALayer and set yourself as the delegate. Then implement `drawLayer:inContext:` and use the context the context that is passed as an argument.

Setup

```
CALayer *yourLayer = [CALayer layer];
// other layer customisation
yourLayer.delegate = self;
```

And draw

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    // Check that the layer argument is yourLayer (if you are the 
    // delegate to more than one layer)

    // Use the context (second) argument to draw.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see that method, `drawLayer:inContext:`, but I don't know if I have to send a message to it or not.

Comment: @VansFannel If you are the layers delegate then that method will be called for you when the layer should redraw

Comment: I have added `QuartzCore` framework, and on header file I've added `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` but I get the following error: `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CALayerDelegate'`.

Comment: @VansFannel That is because it is one of those delegates that don't have a protocol. The delegate property is simply `id`.

Answer (score 1):

The `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` only return a valid context when called from sprecific methods or of you created a new one f.e. by calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`.

So what you need to do, is either subclass a `UIView` and overwrite it's `drawRect:` method with the code in your `drawRadiantGradient` method. Or you could use the delegate methods provided by the `CALayerDelegate` protocol. Just set the layer's delegate to your vc and implement the `drawLayer:inContext:` method. This could look like this:

in your .h file:

```
@interface MyVC : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *drawingView;    
/...
```

and in your .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.drawingView.layer.delegate = self;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    [self drawRadiantGradientInContext:context];
}
```

Comment: I have added `QuartzCore` framework, and on header file I've added `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` but I get the following error: `Cannot find protocol declaration for 'CALayerDelegate'`.

Comment: CALayerDelegate is an informal protocol; you can't declare conformance to it.

Comment: I think you're wrong. You can't assign a delegate of a view's layer because the view is layer's delegate. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom subclass of UIView that draws the gradient in its `drawRect:` method, and have your VC create a radial-gradient view and add that as a subview of its view.

Comment: I need a `CALayer`, so I think I can implement your answer, drawing radiant gradient on `draw:`, using a custom `CALayer`, isn't it?

Comment: @VansFannel: You could use a custom CALayer (in which case you would do the work in `drawInContext:`), but why do you need a layer specifically?